# Deriving expected value given expected value

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance, expected-value

Say I am given two random variables A and B along with their expected values, expected value of their squares and variances:

$$
E[A] = 5, E[B] = 2, Var(A) = 10, Var(B) = 12, E[A^2] = 20, E[B^2] = 16
$$

I am given two random variable $C = AB$ and $D = A(2+B)$ and asked to find the expected value and variance of the random variable C.

Am I safe to assume that the only required step is to substitute values of $AB$ in $C$ for the Expected values and variance respectively or am I missing something?

Comment: What does $AB$ mean?  The product of the two?  But of course the mean of the product need not be the product of the means...let $X$ be $1,2$ with equal probability and let $Y=\frac 1X$.  Then $E[X]=\frac 32, \,E[Y]=\frac 34$, but $XY=1$.

Comment: Indeed is the product. I see your point, but in that case what would be the correct approach to derive the expected value if I am only given the expected values of the individual random variables.

Comment: As my example shows, you can't.  You need information regarding the actual distributions and their dependence, if any.

Comment: I  read somewhere that if they are independent you can multiply them, I guess I will go with that. Thanks for your help lulu.

Comment: Yes, if they are independent then you can do that.  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) is a reference.  Note that your post did not specify that the variables were independent.  That's a very strong assumption.